# jquery fades out immediately rather then .on('click')

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have several div tags and want to be able to create another one with jquery (on click #four), then fade it in and then fade it out on another click.

```
<body>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="four">four</div>
</body>
```

But my code fades out #five right away although I've tried to select the .on('click') for the fadeOut everywhere but the same area as for fadeIn ('#four')

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#four").on('click',function() {
    var newbox = $('<div id="five">five</div>');
    $(newbox).hide().insertAfter("#four").fadeIn('slow');
    });
})

$(document).ready(function() {
$('body:not(#four)').on('click', function() {
$("#five").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Any idea where I'm mistaken? Thanks, Filip

Comment: body doesn't have an ID attribute #four

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//$("#four").on('click',function() { //the user can creat as many div as he wants
$("#four").one('click',function() { //the user fire this event only once
 var newbox = $('<div id="five">five</div>');
 newbox.on('click', function(){ 
   $(this).fadeOut();
 });
 newbox.hide().insertAfter("#four").fadeIn('slow');
});
})
```

if you declare `newbox` as `$("<tags>")` you don't need to use again `$(newbox)` because you already selected it.

Other solution is to `delegate` `event`

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
   if($(e.target).attr('id') === 'four') return false;
   $("#five").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works exactly as I wanted, just one more question. How can I prevent the user from creating multiple div tags but I want him to be able to constantly switch between in and out state...

Comment: to prevent the creation of oother "five" div's I'll change `on` to `one` . Perhaps i didn't get your second request

Answer (score 2):

Your click event is propagating up the DOM tree and firing on the body. So your single click event actually triggers both.

Change the selector to this: `div:not(#four)`

Here's a link to a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkMmx/

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: thanks, this is great but what if I wanted the fadeout effect on the entire screen on click? I tried to made a wrapper div but that did not work...

Comment: @user2600159 It depends on your code structure and what you're really trying to accomplish. You want the DIVs to be inside of a wrapper and clicking on the wrapper will hide the wrapper and its children?

Answer (score 0):

'body:not(#four)' does not mean what you think it means.  This means any body element that does not have the id 'four'.

What is happening is the click event first fires on your 'four' div and then bubbles to the body (which does not have the id four), whose click event is then fading out 'five'.